# Vue.js : v-bind:class if an array exist and that array include something

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Laravel and Vue.js to create multiple users. I'm creating an array of users and filling the field needed to save them into the table. When all field are filled, I loop the array of users within vue.js and send them one by one to the server-side. The server-side validate them (is username and email unique value). If an error occurs, it send it back to client-side. On the client-side, the loop stop, then it add and errors array to the user.

```
this.users.user.push(response.data);
```

I want to show the errors this way:

```
<td class="form-group" v-bind:class="{ 'has-error': users[index].errors.includes('username') }">
    <input v-model="user.username" type="text" class="form-control full-width">
</td>
```

**The problem is** that before the validation happen on server-side, there is no errors array into user. I could push an empty array into the user model before adding it to users, but I want to know if there is an other way to achieve this.

Is there another if statement that can replace `users[index].errors.includes('username')` to check if errors exist and then will check if that errors array include username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
v-bind:class = "{ 'has-error': users && users[index] && users[index].errors && users[index].errors.includes('username') }"
```

This will handle the `undefined`

Comment: Thank you, it's exactly what I needed. I did not thought that the logic test will stop at the moment something is false.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer is absolutely right. One way to keep such computations separate from markup without making it a lot to take is using `methods`:

```
v-bind:class="getMyClasses(index, 'username')" //replace username with the field name

methods: {
  getMyClasses: function (index, field) {
    return {
      has-error: this.users && this.users[index] &&
                 this.users[index].errors &&
                 this.users[index].errors.includes(field)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also a good answer, you should add the field_name in your function instead of username. Actually your function is only good for username.